# Одновременный импорт CSV в базу SQL MariaDB с перезаписью существующих данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, csv, mariadb

Есть ли способ массового импорта CSV-файлов с перезаписью существующих данных?

Ситуация такова, есть БД на MariaDB, есть CSV-файлы (100 шт. = 50ГБ) нужно импортировать в таблицы SQL с перезаписью существующих данных, но в ручную импортировать слишком долго. Может есть какой то способ через командную строку сделать пакетный импорт, так же с переводом с перезаписью существующих данных? Или может иной способ облегчить задачу, например конвертировать в sql фал потом с перезаписью обновить?

Пробовал в ручную загружать с изменением, выдаёт ошибку: AED8C8C1CAC0 SQL (1366): Incorrect integer value. Куда копать?

Comment: *с переводом* с аглицкого на русский? из рублей в евро? что вообще имеется в виду? *Может есть какой то способ через командную строку сделать пакетный импорт* имея полсотни имён файлов, сделать консольный скрипт для их загрузки в БД - дело на две минуты. *с перезаписью существующих данных* Удалить всё из таблиц и залить новое из CSV.

Comment: @Akina, что подразумевается под переводом мне так же не ясно, в инструкции по обновлении базы так написано, при этом в той же инструкции, написано не удалять записи из таблиц, а загрузить сначала файлы базы sql (около 100 гб), потом сделать импорт CSV-файлов с переводом и с перезаписью существующих данных без удаления таблиц.

Comment: Ну так запросите пояснения у авторов инструкции. А то прям "поди туда не знаю куда ..."

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE во временную таблицу, а затем обновление.

Comment: Как я понял из командной строки заходим в базу и выполняем `LOAD DATA INFILE 'с:/download/files/data.csv' ` в новую созданную временую таблицу? А как потом в этой временной таблицы сделать обновление в постоянную? При этом управляющие символы (разделители срок) указывать не надо, без проблем должно загрузиться?

Comment: *Как я понял* Да. *А как потом в этой временной таблицы сделать обновление в постоянную?* Обычным UPDATE (может, ODKU). *управляющие символы (разделители срок) указывать не надо, без проблем должно загрузиться?* Если указана правильная спецификация для LOAD, то разделители в процессе импорта будут убраны.

Comment: Не работает `LOAD DATA INFILE 'с:/download/files/data.csv'`, вообще ничего не происходит. Какие еще предложения могут быть?

Comment: *вообще ничего не происходит* НЕ БЫВАЕТ. Если запрос добрался до сервера - сервер ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО чем-то ответит. Если не зависнет наглухо (процесс или весь сервер). А посему - постарайтесь всё же получить ответ сервера (например, выполните запрос консольным клиентом) и процитировать результат.

Comment: не виснет и нечего не происходит, даже из консоли, ждал почти весь день, вот скриншот http://prntscr.com/mpv8b0 . Пробовал из консоли так загрузить`\. /путь/к/dump.csv` , но так выдаёт ошибку `ERROR 1064 (42000) have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"id","supplierid","datasupplierarticlenumber"`

Comment: *ждал почти весь день, вот скриншот* [facepalm] А сервер весь день ждал, когда ему введут символ завершения команды...

Comment: Я только учусь пользоваться консолью, к сожалению, всех команд не знаю, собственно по этому и задал тут вопрос, как можно массово импортировать (обновить) базу данных. А какой символ завершения команды, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: *The default is the semicolon character (;).* [mysql Client Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html)

Comment: Точку с запятой я использовал, выдаёт ошибку 1064, писал выше.